# Practical Django Project urls.py error

Tags: django, git, github, django-urls

I'm on page 75 of this book but kept getting this error

TemplateSyntaxError at /admin/
Caught SyntaxError while rendering: invalid syntax (urls.py, line 1)

Can't seems to find the problem.

I setup a git at Github, you can check out the codes there.
https://github.com/mrsmith123/Practical-Django-Project

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In `coltrane.urls` line 1:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults imports *
```

should be `import`

Whnever you get a `SyntaxError` the problem is going to be very direct.  Just look at the line that the Error is being raised on or the line before it and 99% of the time that should solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, I thought it was an obvious error but I deleted the * but it's still got the same error.

Comment: You should change `imports` to `import` that's what was wrong with it (not the `*`).